# What model is this Bottecchia bike?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I'm trying to find a decent racing bike for my next triathlon (on the cheap). I saw this bike on Craigslist with no information about the model or features. Can anyone help me figure out what bike this is and how much it is worth?[image]

Comment: usually a vintage bike costs around $100-$200. A vintage bike is fun to ride but it's heavy since a lot of its components are made of steel. Moreover, the components are quite difficult to upgrade since the drivertrain is an old model, and the wheels are 27" instead of 700c.

Answer (score 3):

Bottecchia are an Italian brand who sell everything from BMX bikes to professional racing bikes. Here in the US the brand is probably best known for being ridden by Greg LeMond in his historic 1989 Tour de France win.

It's hard to say the exact model of this bike. It's a low end model from the 1970s "bike boom". The crankset appears to be a Nervar cottered steel unit. The shifters and derailleurs look like low end Huret models. Both are typical of early 70s bikes.

Depending on your budget you could almost certainly do better than this. Bikes have made tremendous gains since the late 80s. Not only have they gotten lighter but they've also become more reliable. I would look for something more recent.